# How to iterate row by row in a pandas dataframe and look for a value in its columns

Tags: python, pandas

I must read each row of an excel file and preform calculations based on the contents of each row. Each row is divided in columns, my problem is that I cannot find a way to access the contents of those columns.

I'm reading the rows with:

```
for i in df.index,:
    print(df.loc[i])
```

Which works well, but when I try to access, say, the 4h column with this type of indexing I get an error:

```
for i in df.index,:
    print(df.loc[i][3])
```

I'm pretty sure I'm approaching the indexing issue in the wrong way, but I cannot figure put how to solve it.

Comment: there is `iterrows()` for a dataframe. Look [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html)

Comment: You normally do not iterate through the rows of a dataframe. You may expect a more useful answer if you provide an example of your dataframe and the operation that you want to apply.

Comment: also, loc does not give you a list to access, would be `.loc[column]` `.loc[column, index]`, `.loc[[columns,...],[indexs,...]]` [Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

Comment: `loc` is used to access data by labels (column names or indices), `iloc` is used to access data by row and column position (i.e. integer). You can combine them: `df.loc[some_index].iloc[3]`

Answer (score 5):

You can use iterrows(), like in the following code:

```
for index, row in dataFrame.iterrows():
  print(row)
```

But this is not the most efficient way to iterate over a panda DataFrame, more info at [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24871316/9380597)